# Why the words do not contain in my dictionary (c++ trie)?

Tags: c++, linux

I think there's something wrong in my implement of trie. I use the word apple to test it. Although my test file `dict.txt` contains the word `apple`, it returns `false`. What's bug?

```
class Trie{

private:

    class Node{

    public:
        Node* next[26];
        bool isWord;
        Node(){ isWord = false; }
    };
    Node* root;

public:

    Trie() { 
        root = new Node(); 
    }

    void load(const string& line) {

        Node* node  = root;

        for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++){
            char x = line[i];
            if(node->next[x-'a'] == nullptr)                    
                node->next[x-'a'] = new Node();
            node = node->next[x-'a'];
        }

        node->isWord = true;
    }

    bool contains(const string& word) {
        Node* node = root;

        for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++){
            char x = word[i];
            if(node->next[x-'a'] == nullptr)
                return false;
            else
                node = node->next[x-'a'];
        }

        return node->isWord;
    }

    bool startWith(const string& prefix) {
        Node* node = root;

        for(int i = 0; i < prefix.size(); i++){
            char x = prefix[i];
            if(node->next[x-'a'] == nullptr)
                return false;
            else
                node = node->next[x-'a'];
        }
        return true;
    }
};


int main() {

    Trie trie;

    ifstream inFile;
    string line;
    while(getline(inFile, line)){
        trie.load(line);
    }
    cout << trie.contains("apple") << endl;
    cout << trie.startWith("cata") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and single step through your code.  Yes, code inspections are a good thing, but I think you could resolve this faster with a debugger than waiting for replies on StackOverflow.

Comment: You forgot to initialise `next`, giving you an undefined program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize pointers `Node* next[26]` to `nullptr`s. And, because of that, words may be added incorrectly. Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should initialize them, thank you!!

Comment: Please, check my suggestion. I'm still not sure whether this is your cause.

Comment: Hi, here's the thing, my test dictionary (dict.txt) actually doesn't contain the word "apple". Then I tried some words that do contain in dict.txt to test my tire, it worked! But to my surprise, no matter the pointers are initialized or not, it always works.